# Named import from React Context don't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Here is my context setup:

```
export const myContext = Rect.CreateContext({
  strings:[],
  addString(newString){
    this.strings.push(newString)
  }
})
```

In one of my nested components I'm trying to do the following:

```
class myComponent extends Component{
static contextType = myContext;

 myFunction(){
  const { addSting } = this.context ;

  addString('mystring'); //- this causes "TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined"

  this.context.addString('mystring'); //- this runs fine 
 }
}
```

Why I cannot use "`addString`" method without specifying `this.context`?

Comment: it should be `this.strings.push()` isn't it ? as you have defined strings not string in your context

Comment: @CodeManiac sorry it was a typo on my end, question is still valid

Comment: You extracted `{ addSting }` from context but you are calling addString. I think it should be `{ addString }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your destructure you are missing the "r" in string

try

```
const {addString} = this.context
```

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, i corrected it in my question